# WSGI Cookies : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, cookies, mod-wsgi, wsgi

```
def application(environ, start_response):

    try:
        co.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])
        i = 1
    except(KeyError):
        i = 2

    c2 = co.get('1').value
```

the problem is the last line.. when there is no cookie named "1".. it simply fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

should i try something like..

```
 try:
    c2 = co.get('1').value
 except(AttributeError):
    i = "test"
```

?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation on `get` method?

Comment: i read something about "dont use get method do direct access instead" but that resulted in errors also. in this example above the if i set data to co.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE']) all i get is the whole cookie string.. nothing to directly access. the string even contains the "SetCookie:" command infront of it.

Comment: oh wait.. i had this code.. perhaps this might work : o1 = cookie.get('1') and cookie['1'].value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one `NoneType` object: None. Just check that `co.get("1")` is not None.